# CsvHelper - .CurrentRecord / .Context.Record replacement in current version of CsvHelper

Tags: c#, vb.net, csvhelper

For the current CsvHelper version, how do you get the string() you used to be able to get with:

- csv.CurrentRecord() -> older versions.
- csv.Context.Record() -> more recent versions.

Able to find [info on the change](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1316) from CurrentRecord to Context.Record, but that does not seem to work in current version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think I found the answer:

csv.Context.Parser.Record

Found comment in Repository's issues stating most methods from .Context had been distributed to .Parser and .Reader.